# Qt's plugin path and WOW64

Tags: windows, qt, 32-vs-64-bit

We are trying to set up a Qt development/runtime system for our users at work. This should allow them to build and/or run either a 32-bit or 64-bit Qt application at their discretion (on the same machine).

The problem is that if we don't do anything, the user gets the dreaded "This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" dialog. Even the prebuilt executables like the designer give you this.

The only ways we've found to fix this are to either add a qt.conf file pointing to the correct plugins directory for that executable's bittage, or to copy the correct "plugins" directory hierarchy underneath the executable's directory. We can do that with custom Visual Studio build rules, but it's a major [PITA](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PITA#Noun). It seems like there ought to be a way to do it globally.

I tried setting the environment variable QT_PLUGIN_PATH to %ProgramFiles%\Qt\Plugins , but it only works for the 64-bit EXE files. For some reason, even the 32-bit EXE files get the %ProgramFiles% expanded to "C:\Program Files\". As near as I can tell, Qt doesn't check anything in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE, so I can't redirect that way.

It seems like there ought to be a way to do this. Is there?

Comment: It's not possible for that system variable on a 64-bit system to point to the 64-bit program files in a 32-bit process

Comment: This behavior is handled by Windows.  So if your using the variable in any way what I describe would be the case.  I am not exactly sure the reason you would have to point to the installation directory of Qt because thats certainly not the case with say the QT Bitcoin client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I finally hit on was using Windows' file redirection of `%windir%\system32`, which is not under any control of the executable. This involves:

- setting QT_PLUGIN_PATH to `%windir%\system32\Qt-plugins`
- copying the 64-bit version of Qt's plugins\platforms directory to %windir%\system32\Qt-plugins\
- copying the 32-bit version of Qt's plugins\platforms directory to %windir%\sysWOW64\Qt-plugins\

Obviously an application installer would also have to perform these steps.

Comment: Note that my first crack at this used QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH. This mostly worked, but caused some weird directory-sensitive startup crashes. I haven't had any trouble with QT_PLUGIN_PATH